# How to determine when features were introduced into React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies

I am currently creating a package which I will publish on NPM. My package uses React but I don't want to add it as a dependency in my package to avoid consumers of my package from ending up with multiple versions of React in their projects (which will always be React projects as my package is React specific), thus bloating their projects unnecessarily.

Therefore I am going to add React to my package as a peer dependency.

My package uses React.Component, React.isValidElement and React.createElement. Therefore I need to find the oldest version of React which supports these features and make this version the minimum version in my peer dependency.

I am struggling in determining how to determine which version of React to use. If anybody is able to offer advice on how to work this out then I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), the minimum version you can depend on is `0.13.0`. I would recommend setting your dependency version to `>=0.13.0`. It would be best to use a CI tool like Travis to test your build on many versions of React (starting at the minimum) to ensure that you don't accidentally break things by relying on newer features.

## Introductions

- `Component` in `0.13.0` (Support for using ES6 classes to build React components)
- `isValidElement` in `0.12.0` (`React.isValidComponent` --> `React.isValidElement`)
- `createElement` in `0.11.12` (`Added React.createElement API in preparation for React v0.12`)